# SendMessage to Application.Handle not working

Tags: delphi, sendmessage, postmessage

I've created an class that should propagate to the entire application a customized message when its going to be freed.
I did it with `PostMessage` and it worked with few bugs

```
PostMessage(Application.Handle, UM_MYMESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

then I realized it should be synchronous - via `SendMessage`.

```
SendMessage(Application.Handle, UM_MYMESSAGE, 0, 0);
```

On my Form I was handling the messages with a `TApplicationEvents` component, but just switching `SendMessage` to `PostMessage` didn't make it handle the message

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message = UM_MYMESSAGE then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Ok');

    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

It works if I pass the Form Handle but not working with `Application.Handle`...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you've found out, ApplicationEvents can only expose posted messages. You might have as well hit F1 on OnMessage to confirm.

Comment: thanks for the light.. can You help me on how to handle the message then?

Comment: I don't understand what entire application means, so hard to comment. Perhaps you can use "broadcast", or install a hook, or loop through forms - or explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake by forcing this through the application window handle, or even via a message at all. Just call a function directly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan when my object is destroyed it should call that to look for its own reference in any List in the application and remove itself from there.
Any other idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I've no idea what you are talking about

Comment: @luix10 either 1) give the object a pointer to the list so it can remove itself from the list; 2) have the object expose an OnDestroy event/broadcast that list maintainer(s) can assign a handler to remove the object from each list; 3) derive the object from `TComponent` (if not already) and utilize its `FreeNotification()` mechanism to detect when the object is destroyed so you can remove it from list(s).

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, I will think about those options.

Comment: @RemyLebeau just to finish this, how to implement the FreeNotification (option 3) you suggested?

Comment: @luix10 Did you read the [`FreeNotification()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FreeNotification) documentation? When you call `FreeNotification()` on a `TComponent`-derived object, it automatically calls the [`Notification()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Notification) method of whatever `TComponent` you pass to `FreeNotification()`. So, register whatever `TComponent` you want to be notified when an object is freed, and have that component override `Notification()` to remove the freed object from your list(s).

Answer (score 6):

The `TApplication(Events).OnMessage` event is triggered only for messages that are **posted** to the main UI thread message queue.  **Sent** messages go directly to the target window's message procedure, bypassing the message queue.  That is why your `OnMessage` event handler works with using `PostMessage()` but not `SendMessage()`.

To catch messages that are **sent** to the `TApplication` window, you need to use [`TApplication.HookMainWindow()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HookMainWindow) instead of `TApplication(Events).OnMessage`, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HookMainWindow(MyAppHook);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.UnhookMainWindow(MyAppHook);
end;

function TForm1.MyAppHook(var Message: TMessage): Boolean;
begin
  if Message.Msg = UM_MYMESSAGE then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Ok');
    Result := True;
  end else
    Result := False;
end;
```

That being said, a better solution is to use [`AllocateHWnd()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) to create your own private window that you can post/send your custom messages to, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyWnd := AllocateHWnd(MyWndMsgProc);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DeallocateHWnd(FMyWnd);
end;

procedure TForm1.MyWndMsgProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = UM_MYMESSAGE then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Ok');
    Message.Result := 0;
  end else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FMyWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

Then you can post/send messages to `FMyWnd`.

Comment: thanks... I'm almost there... didn't figured out how to use TApplication.HookMainWindow() yet...

Comment: Why would you use Windows messages at all just to invoke a function?